# jQuery tweet plugin - tweet formatting adjustment, timestamp and user

Tags: jquery

I need someones very very clever jquery skills as I can't figured out how to do this.

I have made this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/L5uh4/) for help http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/L5uh4/

[image: screenshot]

**Whats Happening...**

I am using this jquery tweet plugin by [sea of clouds](http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/).

In a nutshell, below is my function which displays only **one** tweet. But from an array of twitter users. I have put notes in my function below so you know what is going on...

```
$("#tweet").tweet({
    username: ["seaofclouds", "laughingsquid"],  // array of users
    count: 1,                                    // number of tweets
    loading_text: "loading tweet...",            // loading text
    template: "{avatar}{text}{time}",            // tweet format, in order it appears
    avatar_size: 32                              // avatar size

}).bind("loaded", function(){                    // stuff when loaded

    $("#tweet span.tweet_text").widowFix();

    $("#tweet span.tweet_time").prepend("tweeted by @username "); 

});
```

**My Problem**

As you can see, I have added the timestamp to appear at the end of the tweet using `template: "{avatar}{text}{time}"`

But in this plugin there is NO option for `{user}` - so as you can see I have prepended this text '*tweeted by @username*' to my `span.tweet_time`

This is so it reads... *tweeted by @username about 13 hours ago*

My problem is that I can't get the current tweet username to appear in where '@username' appears

**My Question**

Can some one figure out how to get the current tweet username from the avatar link and add the username (as a twitter user hyperlink) to where @username appears below...

```
$("#tweet span.tweet_time").prepend("tweeted by @username");
```

So the final outputted code will look like this...

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/LaughingSquid" title="View @LaughingSquid on twitter" target="_blank">@LaughingSquid</a>
```

Please see below the outputted avatar html which you can see the twitter link with the username at the end of URL. I hoping someone can use jquery to extract that username?

```
<a class="tweet_avatar" href="http://twitter.com/LaughingSquid">
     <img src="http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/340068086/laughing_squid_logo_normal.jpg" height="32" width="32" alt="LaughingSquid's avatar" title="LaughingSquid's avatar" border="0">
</a>
```

Many thanks in advance for this. This will be a life saver.

Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go ->

[working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5uh4/3/)

the code ->

```
var username = $('.tweet_avatar img').attr('title');
username = username.split("'");
username = username[0];

$("#tweet span.tweet_time").prepend("tweeted by "+ username+" ");
```

Comment: This is totally awesome thanks, so simple. I can figure out from this how to make the link too... but can help me remove the **'s** from the end of the username? Thanks!

Comment: Ignore that last comment. Thank you so much, this is brilliant!

Comment: From your method, this is my finished code, making it a link as well [http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/L5uh4/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/L5uh4/6/) - cannot thank you enough!

Comment: @Joshc Beautiful! Looks great, Joshc. Glad the solution worked for you.